# Is there any difference between #include <linux/ioctl.h> and #include <sys/ioctl.h>?

Tags: drivers, development, sensors, character-device, i2c

I have to write a device driver code for temperature sensor using IOCTL, when I was going through a lot of sample codes, I found while surfing the net, I came across this difference in header file, I counldn't get an accurate answer for it, hence I'm posting it here, hoping that I may get a lead to work with my code.

Answer (score 3):

`sys/ioctl.h` is what you’d use when writing a program which relies on `ioctl`; it defines [the `ioctl` function](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl.2.html) and ends up including `linux/ioctl.h`, which defines macros such as `_IOR`.

`linux/ioctl.h` shouldn’t be referenced directly in user code; however that’s what you’d use when writing a Linux driver.

Basically, if you see `#include <sys/ioctl.h>`, you’re looking at program code; if you see `#include <linux/ioctl.h>`, you’re looking at either kernel (device driver) code, or program code with over-enthusiastic `#include`s.

See also [the Linux kernel documentation on writing `ioctl` interfaces](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/driver-api/ioctl.html).

(In this particular case, the user and kernel view of `linux/ioctl.h` are the same; `ioctl.h` is part of the UAPI in the Linux kernel.)

Comment: +1 for "over-enthusiastic"